# php get access to posted id in ajax request

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

How do I get access to the data that's been posted via ajax request in my php. My ajax request is working to return a string of data but I can't seem to access the variable thats being passed as a json object. What do I to access a json object that only contains one parameter.

jquery:

```
$.ajax({
    type:'POST', 
    url:"../../webservices/get_rating.php",
    data:JSON.stringify({product_id:id}),
    dataType:"html",
    success: function(data) {
        $('.ratings-content').append(data);
    }, error:function(data, status, xhr) {
        alert(data + "\r\n" + status + "\r\n" + xhr);   
    }
});
```

and in my php code its this to get my product_id which doesn't work

PHP:

```
$product_id = (int)$_POST["product_id"];
echo $product_id; always returns 0
```

Comment: What do you mean it "doesn't work?"

Comment: What you've got there looks correct to me. Have you looked at the request headers?

Comment: What do you mean request header what is that?

Comment: You shouldn't need to stringify the data, just pass an actual object to the AJAX request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, `$.ajax` sends data in `GET`, you need to set Type parameter to `POST`. Also you did not set the URL, where the data will be POSTED.

Please check this [link](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for more detail.

Comment: Replace with `data:{product_id:id}` and make sure that id is not a 0

Comment: I tried just putting in '13' but it stills says 0 and this is my return statement echo "" .$product_id;

Answer (score 0):

the default for ajax is $_GET so rither specify POST at the ajax end or use GET on the server side